# Swagger-codegen generates class with field Map<String, List<CurrencyExchangeRateDto>> instead of Map<Integer, List<CurrencyExchangeRateDto>>

Tags: java, swagger-codegen

I have a Spring controller method like the next one:

```
    public ResponseDto<Map<Integer, List<CurrencyExchangeRateDto>>> getCurrencyExchangeRatesForClients(@RequestParam("client-ids") List<Integer> clientIds) {
        ...
        return responseDto;
    }
```

Implementation details were omitted.

And my `ResponseDto` class is as following:

```
public class ResponseDto<T> extends BaseResponse implements IResponse {

    private T data;

    public ResponseDto(int errorCode, String errorMessage, boolean isTechnicalError) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.isTechnicalError = isTechnicalError;
    }

    public ResponseDto(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I generate clients code using `swagger-codegen` as a `data` field I get `Map<String, List<CurrencyExchangeRateDto>>` instead of `Map<Integer, List<CurrencyExchangeRateDto>>`. How can I make `swagger-codegen` to generate `ResponseDtoMapintListCurrencyExchangeRateDto` class with, data field as `Map<Integer, List<CurrencyExchangeRateDto>>` ?

My generated `ResponseDtoMapintListCurrencyExchangeRateDto` class:

```
public class ResponseDtoMapintListCurrencyExchangeRateDto {
  @JsonProperty("data")
  private Map<String, List<CurrencyExchangeRateDto>> data = null;
  ...
}
```

As you can see the type of `data` field is `Map<String, List<CurrencyExchangeRateDto>>` instead of expected: `Map<Integer, List<CurrencyExchangeRateDto>>`.